# express unable to save headers after page reload

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using this method to set authorization header after success login

```
router.post('/attempt', function (req, res, next) {
.....
.....
req.headers.authorization = 'JWT ' + token;
console.trace(req.headers.authorization)
```

and after debug I can see it was set correctly. So I'm trying to debug same headers on the same route but before setting it

```
router.post('/attempt', function (req, res, next) {
    console.error(req.headers.authorization)
```

but it's `undefined`. How can it be? It was set and after page reload cleaned?

Comment: you are not using middleware to attach headers after authorization?

Comment: you mean `passport`? but I assume you are talking about something I need. Now I'm just calling `jwt.sign(user, secret, {expiresIn: 86400 * 30})` after succeed login. and sending the same token with `res.status(200).send`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send headers to the browser then use `res.set();` like

```
res.set('authorization', 'JWT ' + token);
```

but if you want to get to a header from request then use `req.headers` object like

```
var token =  req.headers.authorization;
```

Comment: Don't know why but its not working. `res.set('authorization', 'JWT ' + token); console.trace(req.headers.authorization)` prints `undefined`

Comment: Can you post complete code of `router.post('/attempt' ..)` ?

Comment: and also you should mention client( mobile application, web app for  browser, etc.)

Comment: Its web app (node + express + ejs) and this is the [code](https://pastebin.com/fJ5TsXPn)

Comment: Any insight on how this was fixed? I still can't find a solution, nor can others on SO.