# how authorization works on nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, header, authorization, jwt

I'm trying to understand how authorization works after headers with data were set. I'm using passport and jwt to auth user and setting authorization headers after succeed login attempt.

```
res.setHeader('authorization', 'JWT ' + token);
console.log(res.getHeader('authorization'));
// prints JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwidXNlcl9wYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyeSQxMiR1VUh3czBoeXVYSFhjWTFXWFd2L21ldlNZUFBZcm4xLjdmdEwxb1RSN29mQmxDMEpERE5uLiIsInVzZXJfyMDc1NzM1LCJleHAiOjE1MzQ2Njc3MzV9.F4j6eXpbhPLsLOAixwyNT6PLOUhna1C6CA4iIVbidXsbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM
```

and for example on my main router where only logged in users should be allowed to enter I can't catch this header? It seems like after setting this header its only working until the page is being reloaded. I made [previous question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423211/express-unable-to-save-headers-after-page-reload) but it wasn't specific enough.

I'm starting to think how authorization works and how to set headers or cookies or something after succeed passport authentication?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an interceptor to be created for your http requests where you'll inject the rules for setting headers with each response

```
var http = require('http');

http.Interceptor.register({
    test: {
        uri: '/me/friends',
        host: 'graph.facebook.com'
    },
  rule: {
    response: {
       headers: {
          'Set-Cookie': 'AuthSessId=41D3D0110BA61CB171B345F147C089BD; path=/',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       }
    uri: /^\/dialog\/oauth/,
    host: 'www.facebook.com'

});
```

You can use this npm package for the same and ollow the documentation 
Please visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-interceptor